# Programmatically access members of a UIView subclass in a UIViewController subclass

Tags: swift, uiview, types, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I want to put all subview properties and my subview setup code in a UIView subclass and load that into my UIViewController subclass using loadView(). Then access the UIView subclass members without casting the view property of UIViewController all the time.

This is my UIView subclass `AwesomeClass`

```
class AwesomeView: UIView {
    lazy var testView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        testView.frame = CGRect(x: 10
            , y: 10
            , width: self.bounds.size.width - 20
            , height: 100)
    }
}
```

And my UIViewController subclass `AwesomeViewController`

```
class AwesomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = AwesomeView()
        self.view = view
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I could do something like:

```
var subclassedView:AwesomeView {
    get {
        return self.view as! AwesomeView
    }
}
```

and

```
subclassedView.testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

But is there a way to call `testView` directly with `self.view` in the `AwesomeViewController`?

**Edit:**
What I am looking for is [Covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) in swift.

Comment: Same problem here. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can you something like this:

Instantiate an instance of `AwesomeViewController` in `AwesomeView`

```
class AwesomeView: UIView {

var exampleColorVariable:UIColor?
//here you instantiate your view controller
var awesomeViewController = AwesomeViewController()

lazy var testView:UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.addSubview(view)
    return view
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    testView.frame = CGRect(x: 10
        , y: 10
        , width: self.bounds.size.width - 20
        , height: 100)
  }
}
```

then you can access any method in `AwesomeView` changing a little bit your code

```
 class AwesomeViewController: UIViewController {

   lazy var awesomeView: AwesomeView = {
    let view = AwesomeView()
    view.awesomeViewController = self
    return view
   }()

   func setupView() {
    view.addSubview(awesomeView)
     // your constraints here 
   }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setupView()
    // NOW YOU CAN ACCESS ANY METHOD IN YOUR VIEW awesomeView.yourFunction()
    // or you access that variable 
    awesomeView.exampleColorVariable = .red // you can now omit UIColor in swift3
  }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but i wanted to load the UIView subclass into the UIViewController's view property and not be a subview of that as well as access that view as the type of the UIView subclass. I'm thinking this is not possible in swift right now.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what the var awesomeViewController for? seems like it's initialized when AwesomeView is and then overridden in the lazy loading closure.

Comment: I use the same code in one of my app. Have you tried to see if it can be used in your case?